# Crystal report Group header not show on report footer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, vb6, crystal-reports-xi

[image: Page with group header]

[image: Page with out group header]

[image: Crystal report]

Report footer mark as print at the bottom of page.
Group header is already marked as Repeat group on every page

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because groups are disabled (`hide`)

Try the following:

1. Right-click on the left sidebar on the body you want to view.

[image: actions menu]

2. When opening the action menu, click on `show`.

[image: actions menu show button]